# How to get an attribute value from a table to use in a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table to store table names (lets call it "CUSTOM_TABLES").
I have a table to register data tracking (call it "CONSUMPTIONS").
I have tables that the user was created and I don't know its names (created at runtime) so, the system create the table ( execute the DDL) and store its name in "CUSTOM_TABLES". Lets call it "USER_TABLE" for now.

When a data is produced in a table "USER_TABLE", I register in the tracking table ("CONSUMPTIONS") the row ID of data and the ID of the "USER_TABLE" found in "CUSTOM_TABLES".

Now, I need to find, given a consumption, what table and what row the data is. Remember: in "CONSUMPTIONS" table I have only an ID (FK) pointing to "CUSTOM_TABLES".

```
CREATE TABLE consumptions
(
  id_consumption serial NOT NULL,
  id_row integer,
  id_table integer
)

CREATE TABLE custom_tables
(
  id_table serial NOT NULL,
  description character varying(250),
  name character varying(150)
)
```

The query I need is here:

```
select * from consumptions c
join insurance i on c.id_row = i.index_id
```

In this case, "insurance" is the "USER_TABLE".
But I don't know "insurance". I need to find it in "CUSTOM_TABLES" by using its ID.

```
select name from custom_tables where 
id_table = consumption.id_table
```

The final query must be something like:

```
select * from consumptions c
join 
    (select name from custom_tables t where t.id_table = c.id_table) i 
on c.id_row = i.index_id
```

I guarantee the "user_tables" have "index_id" attribute as its PK.
I prefer do not use functions.

Comment: Seems like you have to build your query dynamically (run-time), to use the current table-name when the query is executed.

Comment: I think about it. But I'm concerning about hitting the database too much. I'ts a scientific application and have an intense data access.